# Shadows not visible in model (Unity3d)

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

I Have model with rung http://prntscr.com/a9r2g6. But If I move forward - then shadews of runs not visible http://prntscr.com/a9r2rt. My lighting settgins http://prntscr.com/a9r2wj. My direction light in scene: http://prntscr.com/a9r3ci

Comment: Hi Utya, if possible click "Edit" and then notice the "image" button.  If you have the points to do so, go ahead and add images to the question.

Answer (score -1):

Well the "shadow type" option in your directional light component is selected as "no shadows".. Choose hard or soft shadow.

Comment: @UtyashevaIrina Try Increasing Shadow Distance in your quality settings.

Comment: I increase shadow distance to 0.1 http://prntscr.com/a9rqqx in all quality settings

Comment: are you checking this in editor mode or play mode. if it is editor mode make sure you toggle on the light mode. [link] (http://snag.gy/t8ih6.jpg)

Comment: I use play mode, in edit mode I use light options (as in screenshot)

Comment: Huh? @UtyashevaIrina, there looks like there's a bit of shadowing in that screenshot you posted in the comments. (On the right side, isn't that bright spot an unshadowed area?) Can you show the staircase section with Hard Shadows on?